# Multi user type design in Laravel

Tags: laravel, multi-user

I'm a bit puzzled on how to best create an architecture for a multiple user type account. Watching the Laracasts episode on users and roles I figured a single User model with a Role model would be a good approach. However, rethinking the data I need for my different type of users varies, as for some users I need full address data and for others a name would be enough (to gently great them upon login). However, a Vistor might turn into a Customer. In fact, even the MerchantEmployee could become a Customer. This makes me wondering what my database design would become, e.g.

```
users => UserModel <fields> email, password
role: visitor => VistorModel <fields> name
role: customer => CustomerModel <fields> name, street, zipcode, ...
role: merchantowner => MerchantOwnerModel <fields> name, street, zipcode, ...
role: merchantemployee => MerchantEmployeeModel <fields> name
```

Would then all the Vistor, Customer, MerchantOwner and MerchantEmployee models have a user_id-column? Or how would you design such functionality?

Comment: I would suggest having the addresses in a separate table. This way if the `role` requires an address it can have one but it doesn't mean a user needs one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to create two tables

First one is `users`

```
+----------+---------+-------+
|   Col    |  Type   | Notes |
+----------+---------+-------+
| id       | bigInt   | PK/AI |
| name     | VARCHAR | NN    |
| email    | VARCHAR | NN|UN |
| password | VARCHAR | NN    |
| role     | ENUM    | NN    |
+----------+---------+-------+
```

The second one is `user_data`

```
+----------------------+---------+-------+
|         Col          |  Type   | Notes |
+----------------------+---------+-------+
| id                   | bigInt  | PK/AI |
| user_id              | bigInt  | FK    |
| address              | VARCHAR | NN    |
| {WHAT EVER YOU WANT) |         |       |
+----------------------+---------+-------+
```

And the relation to be [one to one](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one).

I recommend to use [Laravel validation "required_if"](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-required-if) to valid data before process it to database.

```
$this->validation($request, [
 'address' => 'required_if:role,merchant_owner'
]);
```